# How to make a loop in discord.py rewrite?

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

The bot must do something every 60 seconds.
I tried to use create_task, but it does not work(the bot started but nothing happened). How can this be implemented?

Comment: Use a `for` loop or a `while` loop?  What exactly are you trying to do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`client.loop.create_task` should still work fine with the `rewrite` version. Example of a background task in the `rewrite` version can be found [here](https://github.com/Rapptz/discord.py/blob/rewrite/examples/background_task.py).

```
from discord.ext import commands
import asyncio

client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='!')


async def background_task():
    await client.wait_until_ready()
    counter = 0
    channel = client.get_channel(123456) # Insert channel ID here
    while not client.is_closed():
        counter += 1
        await channel.send(counter)
        await asyncio.sleep(10)

client.loop.create_task(background_task())
client.run('token')
```