# pass async function to thread python

Tags: python, multithreading, discord.py

I am building a Discord bot and most of it is event based. Once the bot is ready, I want to have a thread that, while the bot is alive, sometimes writes "hi" in chat and then sleeps for 2 minutes. Code:

```
async def on_ready(self):
    t = threading.Thread(target=self.say_hi)
    t.start()

async def say_hi(self):
    while True:
        chance = random.randint(0, 101)

        if chance <= 25:
            await self.channel.send('hi')
        time.sleep(60 * 2)
```

Problem is that I get different errors. `RuntimeWarning: Enable tracemalloc to get the object allocation traceback` in this case. I tried following [this somewhat related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59645689/9952624) editing the code in this way:

```
def say_hi(self):
    loop = asyncio.new_event_loop()
    asyncio.set_event_loop(loop)

    loop.run_until_complete(self.say_hi_aux())
    loop.close()

async def say_hi_aux(self):
    while True:
        chance = random.randint(0, 101)

        if chance <= 25:
            await self.channel.send('hi')
        await asyncio.sleep(60 * 2)
```

But the resulting error is `RuntimeError: Timeout context manager should be used inside a task` on `loop.run_until_complete()` method.

I don't know what's wrong with either solution

Comment: Try not caling ``loop.close``

Comment: @JoshuaNixon didn't mention it, but i tried that too. the error is the same as the latter.

Comment: For scheduling stuff in asyncio I used https://phoolish-philomath.com/asynchronous-task-scheduling-in-python.html as a starting point

Comment: @JoshuaNixon I cannot follow the same pattern because things are slightly different, though no result.

Comment: See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54495679/how-to-make-a-loop-in-discord-py-rewrite/54501491#54501491